# Spanning ngFor data across different container div at the length of four

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to continue ngFor data in a new container div when the length gets to four. I hardcoded the data in several div which seems easier, but now i want to dynamically fetch the data using ngFor to displays the data in several container div

**My attempt**

```
<div class="book-section-grid">
  <div *ngFor="let book of books" class="book-section-subGrid">
   <img src="assets/images/book1-1.png" alt="">
   <h4>{{book?.title}}</h4>
   <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What i want to achieve**

```css
.book-section-grid {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1st Section -->
<div class="book-section-grid">
  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2nd Section -->
<div class="book-section-grid">
  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
Run c
```

Comment: take a parent div on the top of the ngFor div. Put the *ngIf condition.
` *ngIf="books.length === 4 `
So it will show only when the length is 4.

Comment: this should be a css solution, not a js solution.  flex box is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Take a parent div on the top of the `*ngFor` div. Put the `*ngIf` condition.
So it will show only when the length is 4.

Try with this one.

```
<div class="book-section-grid" *ngIf="books.length === 4">
  <div *ngFor="let book of books" class="book-section-subGrid">
   <img[src]="book.image" alt="">
   <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
   <span>by <a href="#">{{book.name}}</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have considered your books object have title, name, and image properties.

Your first sentence is bit confusing.

> I want to display my ngFor data in a new container div when the length gets to four

If you want some other solution then please rewrite the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't required new div intentionally you can bind with single div

***template.html***

```
<div class="book-section-grid">
 <div *ngFor="let book of books" class="book-section-subGrid">
  <img [height]="getHeight()" [width]="getWidth()" [src]="book.image" alt="">
  <h4>{{book?.title}}</h4>
  <span>by <a href="#">{{book?.name}}</a></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
getHeight{
    //set custom height based on design or bind in single method
    return (this.books.length <=4)? 50 : 100 ;
}
getWidth{
     //set custom width based on design
    return (this.books.length <=4)? 60 : 110 ;
}
```